# MultiFileUpload in Vaadin - I want to do some task when the last file is uploaded

Tags: java, vaadin, multifile-uploader

I want to do two task at a time

1. uploading multiple files.
2. when all selected files are uploaded then I want to open a window and selecting their type and some other work and then saved it.

When I did it for single upload it works fine.

Now I'm trying to implement multiupload with [MultiFileUpload addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/multifileupload) But the event `public void handleFile(InputStream in, String filename, String mimetype, long length)` is fired for each of the files one by one. I want to open the window when the last file is uploaded. How can I detect that the last file was uploaded?

Here is my code:

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();
    UploadFinishedHandler uploadFinishedHandler = new UploadFinishedHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleFile(InputStream in, String filename, String mimetype, long length) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                String filePath = "/home/yassir/Desktop/";
                File dirFile = new File(filePath);
                if (!dirFile.exists()) {
                        dirFile.mkdirs();
                }
                filePath += filename;

                Button btn = new Button(filename);
                layout.addComponent(btn);
                File file = new File(filePath);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];
                in.read(buffer);
                fos.write(buffer);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };

    UploadStateWindow uploadStateWindow = new UploadStateWindow();
    MultiFileUpload multiFileUpload = new MultiFileUpload(uploadFinishedHandler, uploadStateWindow);
    layout.addComponent(multiFileUpload);
    setContent(layout);
}
```

I will call the function `createWindowType()`(which i didn't add here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the last file upload with [AllUploadFinishedHandler](https://github.com/wbstr/vaadin-multifileupload/blob/master/src/main/java/com/wcs/wcslib/vaadin/widget/multifileupload/ui/AllUploadFinishedHandler.java).

Something like this should work:

```
multiFileUpload.setAllUploadFinishedHandler(new AllUploadFinishedHandler() {
    @Override
    public void finished() {
        //open window here
    }
});
```

This listener is going to be called every time when:

- upload is finished;
- there is no other upload in progress.